# Dockerfile can't copy & Docker-compose volume does not sync with container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am using Docker windows desktop client and trying to build a Flask python container. The dockerfile copies `requirements.txt` and `flask-script.py` files into python container and sets it up.

```
|-root directory (this is where the powershell commands are run from)
|-docker-compose.yml
|-src
|  └── Dockerfile
|  ├── flask-script.py
|  ├── requirements.txt
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask-service:
    build: ./src
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

src/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./flask-script.py" ]
```

Running `docker-compose up` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

**BUT If I change the dockerfile to:**

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./flask-script.py" ]
```

It does work, however after the `docker-compose up` the volume specified in docker-compose does not sync with the container. If I make any changes to the `flask-script.py` file they are not seen by the container.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo, "src" and "scr" are not the same.

Comment: yes, sorry made a typo in the question but the file directories are all correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work when you add the `WORKDIR` because you have all files in that directory.

However, in your first Dockerfile, you copy everything to `/usr/src/app`, but you don't change your workdir to that directory, therefore the `requirements.txt` is not reachable as it's located in `/root/requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now. Would you have any idea why changing the python on the host does not change it in the container?

Comment: @user1031204 in theory that looks fine. Maybe using the same directory as build context and as shared volume is messing something in docker.

Comment: I thought so too and tried to map a different directory which does override the dockerfile that volume is mapping correctly but sadly any change in the python file is not refrected in the container

Comment: @user1031204 when you say that any changes in `flask-script.py` are not seen by the container, do you mean that you edit the file, visit the website, and don't see any change? If this is the case, that's expected. You are editing a file, but the process is already running. In order to check the new changes, you would need to re-run the process, but doing so would terminate the container as the process would have finished. In other words, you can edit on the fly **static** files, but you cannot edit running processes.

Comment: That is what I thought as well but it seems to work here: https://youtu.be/Qw9zlE3t8Ko?t=381